# Why is bson.dumps escaping my list of dicts (jsons)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, mongodb, flask, bson

I'm using mongo.db to host a collection of jsons, which I turned into a list of jsons using

```
    cursor = finder.find_pokemans(db) #this just searches the db for query and works fine
    all_pokemon = [k for k in cursor]
```

But when I pass the list to jinja2 so I can work with it in as a list of jsons using the following line:

```
return render_template('index.html', list_all_pokemon = bson.json_util.dumps(all_pokemon))
```

this line in my html template (I'm using inline js)

```
var all_pokemon = {{ list_all_pokemon }};
```

turns into

```
var all_pokemon = [{&#34;_id&#34;: {&#34;$oid&#34;: &#34;5ca40f82f2463129878bdd93&#34;}, &#34;id&#34;: 1, &#34;name&#34;: &#34;Bulb
```

In other words, it escapes all my quotes so it's unusuable as a json.
I tried jsonifying in the list comprehension line and json.dumps in the variable passing, but I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
```

Any clues as to how to fix this?

EDIT: I can use

```
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
return render_template('index.html', list_all_pokemon = JSONEncoder().encode(all_pokemon))
```

and it will work fine, but I was wondering why I can't json.dumps or jsonify like other scenarios and whether I can use those formats instead here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ list_all_pokemon }}` is a string - Jinja2 will HTML-escape any string that is not marked as HTML-safe.

You can avoid this escaping by doing so: `{{ list_all_pokemon | safe }}`... But as it happens, Jinja2 knows how to do it by itself. This is the proper way to do what you want:

```
var all_pokemon = {{ all_pokemon | tojson }};
```

In the old Flask you were also required to mark this as safe, as it didn't do it for you (`{{ all_pokemon | tojson | safe }}`) but I believe current Flask does not require you to.

Comment: Hi, that worked, sort-of. 
Now I'm left with a string that resembles a list of jsons:

`
[{"_id": {"$oid": "5ca40f82f2463129878bdd93"}, "id": 1, "name": "Bulbasaur", "type": ["Grass", "Poison"],...
`

Is there a concise way to now convert these to jsons?

Comment: That's not a list of JSONs. `["{\"a\": 1}", "{\"a\": 2, \"b\": \"foo\"}"]` is a list of JSONs. What you have is JSON that consists of a list of objects (which, when inserted into JavaScript, will become a JavaScript list of objects). What, exactly, do you want, if not that?

Comment: var all_pokemon = {{ list_all_pokemon | safe | tojson}};
  console.log(all_pokemon);
  console.log(typeof(all_pokemon))

shows me that it's a string.

Comment: I noticed late that `list_all_pokemon` is a string, and corrected in my answer: you need `{{ all_pokemon | tojson }}`. (Not `list_all_pokemon`). If you insert `list_all_pokemon` (which is a string), you get a string in JavaScript - precisely what you said it should do. If you give it a list (`all_pokemon`), JavaScript gets a list.

Comment: Alright thanks so much. As it turns out, I just need to pass list_all_pokemon = dumps(all_pokemon) and call var all_pokemon = {{ list_all_pokemon | safe}}; to achieve my desired effect.

Comment: Yep, you can do that too. But in general I don't like to do so, as JSONification here is not a part of your business logic, but of presenting data to the view, so giving `all_pokemon` to jinja2 and letting it convert it `tojson` is what I'd prefer to see. However, aside from code organisation, `dumps` followed by `{{ list_all_pokemon | safe }}` is doing exactly the same thing as `{{ all_pokemon | tojson }}`.